# Optimization Problem: Minimizing Total Cost of All Pairs

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, combinations, discrete-optimization

This is related to a real-world problem I'm solving but I'm keeping it abstract so I don't bog you down with details. An efficient answer to this feels like it should be obvious but I'm not seeing it. Let me know if there's a better place to ask this.

---

Given some letters and some numbers, I need to generate the most efficient letter-number pairing.
letters: a-z
numbers: 0-99
result: {a:46, b:27, c:13, ...}

For each of the C(26,2)=325 letter pairs, there exists a frequency of how likely it is for that letter pair to occur. Ex: {'th': 0.03}
For each of the C(100,2)=4950 number pairs, there exists a cost for how expensive it is to transition between those two numbers. Ex: {(32,17): 53}

Pair each number with a letter, such that the total cost of all letter combinations (frequency*cost) is as low as possible.

---

Hopefully this makes sense. Is there some elegant way to do this that doesn't involve brute-forcing the solution?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4061893/14578, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/90652/8560, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/136637/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance of the [quadratic assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_assignment_problem), which is a generalization of the traveling salesman problem.  It is difficult to solve large instances optimally, but using an integer linear programming solver will generally perform much better than brute force.